# how do I make a nav with hexagon-shaped links in html

Tags: html, css

i've been workinng on a website and I can't figure out how to make a nav made of hexagons, with four hexagons glued together and each one of them is a link just like this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMVOZ.png.
please could someone help me...

Comment: This helps on the CSS hexagon grid: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/

Answer (score -2):

here you have a guide about making shapes with HTML and CSS. Also check the other link that is attach about positioning.

Shapes: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

Objects example: http://jsfiddle.net/zQzSJ/1/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="band_wrap clear">
        <div class="band"></div>
        <div class="band"></div>
    </div>
</div>



.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
}
.wrap > div.circle {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #aaa;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.band_wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
.wrap .band {
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```